# Limit of exponential of sines and cosines

Tags: calculus, limits, solution-verification

The task is to calculate
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} e^{x \ln (\sin(1/x)+\cos(1/\sqrt x)}.$$
Since $\lim_{u\rightarrow 1}\ln u\approx u-1$, the original limit can be rewritten as
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} e^{x  (\sin (1/x)+\cos ((1/\sqrt{x})-1)} = \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} e^{x (1/x -1 -1 )} = e.
$$

However, the solution manual says $\sqrt{e}$ is the correct answer. Can you help me figure out why? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Maclaurin's expansions:

- $\sin\frac1x=\frac 1 x+o\bigl(\frac 1x\bigr)$,
- $\cos \frac1{\sqrt x}=1-\frac1{2x}+o\bigl(\frac 1x\bigr)$ (from MacLaurin's expansion at order $2$ and substitution).

We deduce that the expansion of the exponent is
\begin{align}x \ln \biggl(\sin\Bigl(\frac{1}{x}\Bigr)+\cos\biggl(\frac{1}{\sqrt x}\biggr)\biggr)
&=x\biggl(\ln\Bigl(\frac1x+1-\frac1{2x}+o\Bigl(\frac 1x\Big)\biggr)=x\biggl(\ln\Bigl(1+\frac1{2x}+o\Bigl(\frac 1x\Bigr)\Bigr)\biggr)\\
&=x\biggl(\frac1{2x}+o\Bigl(\frac 1x\Big)\biggr)=\frac12+o(1).
\end{align}
Is it clear now?

Comment: Yes. Thanks. However, how can you tell how many terms of the series you're going to need? For the sine you used one term, but for the cosine you used two. Is there a standard way of predicting how many you're gonna need? Because I used 1 term for both, and got the wrong answer.

Comment: What is important is the degree of the last term, not the number of terms. I expanded the sine  at order $1$, and the cosine at order $2$, because after substitution by $1/\sqrt x$, it will also have degree $1$ in $1/x$ (all terms have to be expanded up to the same final degree), and with degree $1$, I can conclude.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks!